# How to publish a QGIS map for use with Garmin/Android?

Tags: qgis, android, garmin

I made a hiking map with QGIS (for printing) and would also like to provide a digital version of the map for Garmin and Android to my consumers.

Garmin:
I know GarminCustomMaps but, the possible map extend and resolution is not good enough for me. And I can not find any other way to bring a QGIS map to Garmin.

Android:
What could be a approach to bring my map to Android. As own App, or as map for an already existing Map-App. It has to work offline and with GPS mode. It would be perfect to have a combination of Raster/Vector, but raster in a good resolution would also be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Maptiler](http://www.maptiler.com/) can do that for you, turning your QGIS maps into map tiles that can be used to set up a tile layer in your MapView view. It's [not the cheapest option](http://www.maptiler.com/pricing/), but it's the easiest I've seen so far.

You need to export your map as a huge image.  The image is automatically saved with location information (in a separate .jpgw or .tifw file) showing the coordinates of the four corners.